# Integer from String via Lambda expression

Tags: java, string, integer

I have a small problem, namely I want to get `Integer` from a `String` via lambda expression. I wrote small code but i get only single chars.

Example:

```
String = "He11o W00rld"
```

I get `[1, 1, 0, 0]` but I want `[11, 00]`. Is there any solution for this?

My code:

```
Function<String, List<Integer>> collectInts = f -> { 
    return f.chars()
            .filter( s -> (s > 47 && s < 58))
            .map(r -> r - 48)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());};
```

Comment: Any particular reason you need to do it by lambda expression?

Comment: Yes i must do this for study exercises...

Comment: Take a look at [`Pattern#splitAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Stream.of(f.split("[^\\d]+"))
  .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())  // because of the split function
  .map(Integer::parseInt)
  .collect(toList())
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use the following lambda:

```
Function<String, List<Integer>> collectInts = s ->
   Pattern.compile("[^0-9]+")
          .splitAsStream(s)
          .filter(p -> !p.isEmpty())
          .map(Integer::parseInt)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is used [`Pattern.splitAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) stream generator, which splits a given input by regex. Then each part is checked if it is not empty and converted to `Integer`.

Besides, if you need `00` instead of `0`, you should not parse a number (skip `Integer::parseInt` mapping and collect to `List<String>`).